When one charged lepton gets mass through the SM Higgs boson and two others through a different $SU(2)_L$ doublet, what are the constraints on VEVs?
If one charged lepton receives its mass through the SM Higgs boson ($H$), while two others through a different $SU(2)_L$ doublet ($\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$).
What are the constraints on this new scalar doublet, and in particular, on its vacuum
expectation value.
Does it follows $<v_1>^2 + <v_2>^2 +<v_3>^2=(246GeV)^2$.
$v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are the VEVs of $H$, $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ respectively.

It seems to me you are using a physics vocabulary in a confused manner. Have a look at this answer of mine on simple terms, on how particles get a mass in the mainstream standard model :  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461821/

The formula is correct only if there is NO cross terms (NO interaction between different Higgs doublets) in the combined Higgs Lagrangian. Most 3-Higgs-doublet models does include cross terms, so your formula is not correct in that case.

Thank you so much for your reply. So does it mean that we can write only (v_2)^2 + (v_3)^2=(246 GeV)^2.
